# React Native - React Navigation passing params to nested navigators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**Problem:**
I'm trying to pass params to a nested navigator and i'm getting an "undefined is not an object when evaluating 'props.route.params.data'. Not sure my params are getting passed to the screen in the first place.

**Context:**
I'm trying to have my camera screen not have a tab navigator at the bottom, and i want to pass params to CaptureReview screen

**App.js**...

```
   <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />

      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ gesturesEnabled: false, headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} options={{ gestureEnabled: false }} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStack} options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
        })} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainStack} options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
        })} />


        <Stack.Screen
          name="MyCapture"
          component={CaptureScreen}
          options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            headerShown: false
          })}
        />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

**MainNavigation.js** (passed as MainStack to the Stack.Screen above)

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}>
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeStack}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Challenge"
                component={ChallengeStack}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Capture"
                component={CaptureStack}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Discover"
                component={DiscoverStack}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Profile"
                component={ProfileStack}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />

        </Tab.Navigator>
```

In the CaptureStack I'd like to pass a video that i capture from the CaptureScreen (located in my App.js file).

This is how i'm passing the information (from CaptureScreen to CaptureStack -which has a CaptureReview screen)

```
props.navigation.navigate('Capture', { screen: 'CaptureReview', data: video })
```

This is how i'm receiving the information

```
const [video, setVideo] = useState(props.route.params.data)
```

I've also tried the following...

```
 props.navigation.navigate('Main', { screen: 'Capture', data: video })
 props.navigation.navigate('Capture', { screen: 'CaptureReview', data: video })
 props.navigation.navigate('CaptureReview', { data: video })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the params to the nested navigator. Try something like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  activeOpacity={0.8}
  onPress={() =>
  navigation.navigate('TopTabsNavigator', {
   screen: 'TournamentsScreenCreated',
   params: {
    id: item.id,
    name: item.name,
   },
  })
 }
>
```

Now, in your nested navigator, you should receive the params as destructuring prop:

```
export const NestedNavigator = ({route}) => {});
```

All we need is inside the route prop.
Now, we need to send that param to our Tab.Screen but sending it as normal React prop would not work, for that, we are going to use `children` so we can use a JSX component directly:

```
<Tab.Screen
 name="YourScreenName"
 options={{
  tabBarLabel: 'Label Text',
 }}
 children={() => <ComponentName params={route.params.params} />}
/>
```

Finally, consume your params prop in your component that you are using in your Tab.Screen and you are going to avoid the "undefined is not an object when evaluating 'props.route.params.data' error:

```
const ComponentName = ({params}) => {
 console.log(params);
});
```

All above worked for me, I hope it helps you who are reading this too.

Comment: small change for the answer:<Tab.Screen
 name="YourScreenName"
 options={{
  tabBarLabel: 'Label Text',
 }}
 children={({route}) => <ComponentName params={route.params.params} />}
/>